NIFI dynamic XML to JSON
I have an XML containing array field. Each element in this array can have a different schema based on its type.
Currently, I have used NIFI ConvertRecord processor with the below details:

I can parse XML to JSON but the output JSON is not correct.
The first array element schema is converted successfully from XML to JSON but the other element value is null
